# Creating and calling a class method

Tags: class, python-3.x, object, methods

I want to create a method that takes the subtotal (`price` attribute below) of multiple instances (return the total price of dog1 & dog2 .. if a user creates a list with inputs and possibly iterate through that list to return the total price of the pet order)

So far I have this:

```
class dog ():
  def __init__(self, price, age, food, life):
    self.price = int(price)
    self.age = int(age)
    self.food = str(food)
    self.life = int(life)
  def subtotal(self):
    cost = self.price
    return cost
```

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you want to do. Do you want to know how to create a class method, or do you want to know what a approach you should take to solving your issue? Please show some example code of how you would expect this class method would be used an what its output would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dog classes, like `dogs = [dog1, dog2, dog3]`, where you've created them from user inputs or similar (i.e. `dog1 = dog(40, 7, "meat", 9)`), then you can add up all their costs as follows:

```
subtotal = 0
for doggie in dogs:
    subtotal+=doggie.price
print(subtotal)
```

Just a note on form, as well: in general, it's a good convention to capitalize your class names. In your case, you named your class `dog`, but I would recommend renaming it to `Dog`. Hopefully that achieves what you wanted!